# Bootstrap 3 not working with angular-ui paginator

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui

I am attempting to use the angular-ui paginator directive in ui-bootstrap-0.6.0.js in an angular app that uses bootstrap 3.0.2

I started with the example found here: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

```
    <div class="well well-small">
        <pagination class="pagination-small" total-items="bigTotalItems" page="bigCurrentPage" max-size="maxSize" boundary-links="true" rotate="false" num-pages="numPages"></pagination>
    </div>
```

My problem is that the styles to not get applied to the paginator.  I have found that by including the bootstrap 2.3.1 css that the paginator is correctly styled.  But, of course, that messes up everything else.

```
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

What do I need to do to get the paginator to work with bootstrap 3?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that bootstrap 3 is not supported yet.  Thank you Pawel Kozlowski! for the information and the solution.

I got the latest angular-ui from the bootstrap 3 branch on github.  It is working well.

Comment: I can't seem to find a "ui-bootstrap-*.js" file anywhere in the branch.  Which is what I had when I installed this with nuget.  Is it there?